# How to use AddHandler to add event handler for a LostKeyBoardFocusEvent on a button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I am trying to encapsulate some button behaviors and one of which is to add an event handler for event "LostKeyboardFocusEvent", but I got "handler type is mismatched" error in run-time with and SystemArgumentException:

```
AssociatedObject.AddHandler(Button.LostKeyboardFocusEvent, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(HandleButtonToolTip), true);

public static void HandleButtonToolTip(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get tooltip from sender.
            ToolTip tt = (ToolTip)(sender as Control).ToolTip;
            if ((sender as Control).IsKeyboardFocusWithin && !tt.IsOpen)
            {
                ShowButtonTooltip(sender);
            }
            else
            {
                ClearButtonTooltip();
            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
AssociatedObject.AddHandler(Button.LostKeyboardFocusEvent, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(HandleButtonToolTip), true);
```

to

```
AssociatedObject.AddHandler(Button.LostKeyboardFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(HandleButtonToolTip), true);
```

And change

```
public static void HandleButtonToolTip(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
```

to

```
public static void HandleButtonToolTip(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type of the handler from `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs` to `KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler`:

```
AssociatedObject.AddHandler(Button.LostKeyboardFocusEvent, new KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(HandleButtonToolTip), true);
```

...and the type of the `EventArgs` to `KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs`:

```
public static void HandleButtonToolTip(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
...
```